# Getting a background color to be on top of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an overlay to be over an image when I hover over it.
The color that I used to create the overlay doesn't go over the image. It goes around the image and I want it to be on top of the image.
I'm not sure where I went wrong.
It is also does this weird jumping thing when you hover over it.

Html

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay2"></div>
    <figure class="box-img">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PHKC3T9.jpg" alt="" />
    </figure>
  </div>
```

css

```
.overlay:hover{
background: red;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0.7;
}

.box-img img{
position: relative;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zgw5tmrc/)

Answer (score 4):

The large 'border' is because of the default margin and padding of a `figure` element, according to W3 these are the common specs :

```
figure {
display: block;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1em;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
}
```

I always like to do a complete reset myself at the start of the stylesheet :

```
*, *:before, *:after {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

In the current form of your code, the overlay won't show on top though because the color would be in the background. A pseudo element might do what you're after (updated the code here with a direct approach) :

http://jsfiddle.net/j0qfhr9e/

```
<figure class="box-img">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PHKC3T9.jpg" alt="" />
</figure>
```

```
.box-img {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
line-height: 0;
}

.box-img:hover:after {
content: '';
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: red;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0.7;
}
```

The first draft for completeness, closer to the original markup :

http://jsfiddle.net/rLu2c4kr/

Comment: tip: check the 'normalized css' in the fiddle options to reset styles. And +1 for using a pseudo element, you beat me to it ;-) http://jsfiddle.net/zgw5tmrc/2/ Note that you could use `:before` as well, but then you would have to add a z-index as I did in my fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll gladly let you beat me to the next one when it comes to using pseudos. :-D

Comment: Good solution, simple and effective. Less markup +1

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to add that setting `line-height: 0` is *one* way of making sure that the overlay is as big as the image (inline causes a minor size difference). But that the rule can be left out if the image has `float: left` or `display: block` (like in Florian Rivoal's answer) for example - in case it might be interfering with other content in the `figure`. But it would be slightly more characters. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to make this work without psuedo class' like @Shikkediel mentioned you can set the can use a background image instead of an image tag http://jsfiddle.net/zgw5tmrc/3/

```css
body, figure {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
.box-img {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/PHKC3T9.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.box-img:hover .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<figure class="box-img">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  display:block;
}
figure:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom:0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PHKC3T9.jpg" alt="" />
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your markup this way (**Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ctnels/zgw5tmrc/7/)**)

**HTML**

```
<div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="overlay"> </div>
    <figure class="box-img">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PHKC3T9.jpg" alt="" />
    </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay-container {
    width:225px;
    height:225px;
    position: relative;
}
.overlay-container:hover .overlay{
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.box-img img{
    position: relative;
}
```

**Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ctnels/zgw5tmrc/7/)**